# repeatable regions in mailchimp

Tags: templates, mailchimp, regions

I'm having difficulty setting up repeatable regions in Mailchimp. I have several table rows with mc:repeatable tags. I can duplicate and drag and drop these table rows within the campaign editor, however when I look at the newly created order, the order isn't shown in the preview mode.

To test the repeatable regions I downloaded the template from https://github.com/mailchimp/email-blueprints/blob/master/responsive-templates/base_boxed_2column_query.html which had one table row with mc: repeatable on it. I duplicated and moved these rows in different orders and the newly created order was retained within preview mode.

I augmented this downloaded template slightly and added another table row with mc:repeatable to the table that had the original table row with mc:repeatable, so that the structure was now:

```
<table>
<tr mc:repeatable></tr>
<tr mc:repeatable></tr>
</table>
```

With this slight augmentation, the newly created drag'n'drop order is not retained in preview mode. Why? To my knowledge the tr's are not nested and are separate blocks within the table, but they won't re-order. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I received a response from mailchimp. Essentially a repeatable region must be adjacent to (above or below) it's original region. So, in other words, if you create a copy of a block with the repeatable tag, it must be only directly above or below that original block (you can't plop it anywhere you want in the email).

Comment: After testing and testing and testing this seems to be the case, highly annoying little issue indeed

Comment: what a shame, I wanted dragging repeatable blocks between columns ;(

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your "repeatable" row within an editable container, like

```
 <table>
    <div class="ItemInfo" mc:repeatable>
    <tr mc:edit>Description of intended row info to be replaced </tr>
    </div>
    </table>
```

see this [enter link description here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/create-editable-content-areas-with-mailchimps-template-language)